# Is there a word that means diagonal and above?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I’m looking for a word (or even a phrase if there isn’t a word) that would describe cells on a grid.

I want to say that given a cell I want to pick the three cells in the row above that touch my current cell - that is the two cells that are diagonally above mine and the one directly above.

Comment: I don't believe there is a specific word in this instance; is there a reason you can't just say "the cells to the top left, right, and center of my cell"?

Comment: Pick the cells directly and diagonally above this cell.

Comment: Compass directions.  NW, N, NE.

Comment: So long as your context understand that corners are *adjacent*, you can use *adjacently above*.

Comment: You could always say, "the three 'touching' cells above".  I think that would be pretty clear.

Comment: So, there are only three cells? That means the one above yours, the one above that and the one above that second one? Hmm. Sort of odd have that to describe only three cells. You seem to be describing "staggered cells".

Comment: @Lambre: note - "the three cells in the row above" - not the column...